# EventBus and Swing JFrame Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, swing, garbage-collection, guava, event-bus

I am refactoring a Swing application to use Guava's EventBus pretty heavily. The Swing application basically runs a decision process, displays a large collection of results in a JFrame, and then gets disposed once the JFrame is closed. Now it also subscribes to an EventBus to handle user manipulation of the data.

My question is this. I'm worried the EventBus may hold a reference to the JFrame and all of its internal references (including all the model data) once it is closed. Is it enough to add a WindowListener to unsubscribe it from the EventBus so garbage collection can free the data and the underlying model? Or is this something I don't need to worry about?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with EventBus, but yes, by unregistering from the EventBus should remove at least one more strong reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `unregister` all components you previously registered as there is [no WeakEventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/807).

Note that unregistering an object

```
@throws IllegalArgumentException if the object was not previously registered.
```

unless the object has no `@Subscribe` methods. The Javadoc is not exact, as both registering and unregistering such objects do nothing at all (and never throw).

Comment: In general, there should be no problem at all with blindly subscribing all components. The only case in which unsubscribing will fail is if you try to unsubscribe something that has an `@Subscribe` method but which was _not_ previously subscribed.

Comment: @ColinD I see, but there'll be usually many such objects, if you simply recursively subscribe a whole component tree.

Comment: By "many such objects" do you mean objects that you pass to `unsubscribe` that weren't previously passed to `subscribe`? I don't see why there should be any.

Comment: @ColinD My comment was wrong. And so was my answer in this respect (I see I misunderstood [issue 1630](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1630)).  The Javadoc is not correct either (see my edit), right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what all this recursion talk is, and I think its beyond the scope of what I was looking for. I dont have nested recursive subscribe statements although I'm unclear how to do that and why. I'm just making sure garbage collection happens under normal circumstances when unsubscribe is called.

Comment: @ThomasN. What I meant by recursion was traversing a tree of visual components -- so forget it and sorry for the confusion. Right, just unsubscribe everything you've subscribed and you're fine.

Comment: Yeah, IAE will not be thrown when you try to unregister something with no `@Subscribe` methods even if you never previously tried to register that object.